# WCF Architectural Debate

Tags: architecture, wcf

When building a WCF service for a large scale application, which is better:

In both cases, assume that the business logic layer is separated into a different assembly.

---

Using your business logic layer as a service implementation i.e. with no code behind and no wrapper

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="CS" Service="MyApp.BusinessLogic.BusLogicImpl" %>
```

or

Using the codebehind of the WCF service that wraps calls into your business logic layer.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="CS" Service="MyApp.WebServiceHost.Service" CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have code behind your service, I would also put that into a separate assembly and store it in the .\bin directory of your ASP.NET website hosting the SVC file - I would never put that directly into a MyService.svc.cs code-behind file.

So you would have something like:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="CS" Service="MyApp.ServiceLayer.MyService" %>
```

and put all the logic and wrapper code you need (to call your business layer) into that assembly.

Comment: So, the other part of the question is: do you think the wrapper should exist?

Comment: @Matt Ruwe: yes, I think it can be quite useful, to handle things like catching a bunch of exceptions that can happen (network down etc.) and re-creating the client side proxy class if the communications channel is faulted etc.